# I don't want url to be case sensitive CQ5

Tags: weblogic, aem

I am using CQ5.6 and I don't want my website URL to be case sensitive.
For e.g - WWW.abs.com/test and WWW.abs.com/Test should return the same page. 
Kindly, suggest me any good way to do it. 
Can I do it using vanity URL using regexp?

I have deployed my CQ5.6 instance on web logic server. Kindly, let me know if 
anything can be done by making changes in the web logic configuration files. I 
have already tried using web logic console->domain->security->general->advanced->Web app file case insensitive="os" on windows but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a web server in front of the WebLogic server? I would suggesting using Apache with some URL Rewrite rules to normalize the context root to lower case regardless of the incoming case.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a apache rewrite URL which converts incoming URL to lowercase and make sure all pages in AEM are lowercase. If having all page names is not possible then write a listener service which creates an alias for the page which is all lowercase.

Having said that, this does look like an necessary exercise but assuming you have a valid use-case for this.